# X Server Starting Window Manager (Compiz-Standalone) Cursor is Black X

Tags: compiz, window-manager, xserver

I'm running ubuntu server 15.10 using compiz as my window manager. My .xinitrc is:

```
#!/bin/sh
xset s off         # don't activate screensaver
xset -dpms         # disable DPMS (Energy Star) features.
xset s noblank     # don't blank the video device

unclutter -idle 0.1 -root &
/usr/bin/pulseaudio --start &
exec compiz --replace
```

When I run startx it takes me to a blank screen (which is expected) and I can open up terminal with some compiz keyboard commands. However my cursor is a black X when I am hovering over the black screen. If I launch a terminal and hover my mouse over it, it turns to a regular cursor. Any idea why this would be happening.

Note: I have another system, that as far as I know is configured the same, and the cursor behaves normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, for some reason this system is requiring me to set the cursor name in my .xinitrc. So I added this line to my .xinitrc.

```
 xsetroot -cursor_name left_ptr
```

Whats weird is my other system does not have this line in it's .xinitrc and the cursor is behaving normally. Both are running compiz as the WM.